# Sort value according to another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheets prepared: [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnzyGsglNKqEdE85a1BsaldhQVRIMFEtMHBzbWJBNkE&usp=sharing) and in column `I`, I want to list every player in column `B` if the value in column `C` is `Beta`.

What formula do I need to use in column I?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of the meaning of sort in the title of the question, but to get the requirement in the text of your question, in cell `I2` enter

```
=query(A2:C16, "select B where C = 'Beta'")
```

You might want to change the query range to include more rows.

If you want the list sorted, enter instead:

```
=sort(query(A2:C16, "select B where C = 'Beta'"))
```

Also, it looks like that sheet is attached to a **form**. I recommend you do calculations (use formulas) in another sheet not associated with a form.

Comment: @user36867 Welcome to webapps SE. Please upvote if you find the answer useful and eventually mark the answer correct if it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the answer already given, is the following formula in `I2`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(B2:B;C2:C="Beta"))
```

If there are more then one entries to expect, add the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(B2:B;C2:C="Beta")))
```

Sorting the range can be done with the sort function:

```
=SORT(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(B2:B;C2:C="Beta")),1,TRUE)
```

The `1` in the sort represents the first and only column. The `TRUE` will sort the range ascendingly and `FALSE` will sort it descendingly.